# Data Binding as a design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, data-binding, binding

Where can I find a discussion of the Binding in a way similar to GoF?

Comment: In WPF it's called the model-view-viewmodel pattern, if you're looking for a specific implementation of the pattern.

Comment: Thanks Will, thought I was looking for discussion of the Binding itself. Like GoF dicusses Observer that has many applications.

Answer (score 3):

[Paul Stovell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57132/paul-stovell) has an excellent discussion of Binding Oriented Programming.  His website is offline right now, so the closest thing I could find was this article by him:

http://web.archive.org/web/20070516233101/www.paulstovell.net/blog/index.php/binding-oriented-programming/

Here's the link to the original article, I was thinking of;  I can't find a version of it in the way back machine, so hopefully his site will go back up soon!

http://www.paulstovell.com/blog/searchquery-windows-forms-binding-oriented-programming-example

Answer (score 1):

Data binding is a solution to the synchronization problem of the Presentation-Model pattern.

Found this article about it:
http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html

But I'm pretty confident you can find other sources on the internet.